# iterating loop - complexity

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, complexity-theory

I wrote an algorithm to find duplicates in a linked-list.
for each node, I iterate from head of the list to the current node, and if it's a duplicate it is deleted.

what is the complexity of my algorithm?

Comment: It seems for each item you triverse the list to find duplicates and remove.that means you have nested loop and the complexity is O(n^2).It will be better if you can post your code...i am guessing your logic from statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity of the algorithm is `Θ(n^2)` *worst case*, since if there are no dupes, you iterate for each node a linearly increasing number of times, resulting in total of `1 + 2 + .... + n` total reads which is `Θ(n^2)` (from [sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum))

---

At *best case* the complexity is `Θ(n)` - if all elements are dupes The complexity is `Θ(n)`, because at every iteration the list shrinks, which results in at most 2 node reads per iteration, thus `Θ(n)`